# Is the word "lured" an adjective or verb in the sentence "I feel lured by the chance to start over again."

Tags: grammar, verbs, adjectives

While I understand the verb "feel" is often followed by -ed adjectives when talking about emotional states, "lured" itself is not an adjective. So I am not sure what to make of the following sentences:

- I feel lured by the chance to start over again.
- He felt cheated.
- I feel deceived by the leaders of our community.

Are *lured*, *cheated*, and *deceived* verbs or adjectives in these sentences?

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Comment: Why do you think *lured* is not an adjective in this sentence? Not all adjectives can appear in attributive positions. We can say *he was asleep* but not *the asleep man*. Does that mean *asleep* is a not an adjective?

Comment: Trying to understand the question, I guess "lured by the chance to start over again" sounds like a passive with an agent, while "I feel happy" doesn't seem to have the same structure. But it's possible to have an adjective accompanied by a prepositional clause ("The sword was red with the blood of his enemies", "He felt sad with all his responsibilities"). I think someone here has a standard speech about how "adjective" is a role or function, not a class of words.

Comment: Welcome! The words in question are participular forms of verbs, functioning as adjectives. In this context, yes, the word "lured" *is* an adjective ("adjectival," if it makes anyone feel better). We can make similar constructions in all kinds of contexts: "The paper looked wrinkled," "the house smelled mildewed," "the chicken tasted burnt." (or "burned.") Voting to close as based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Andy Bonner I think the CGEL analysis is that once a by-phrase (showing agency, volitional or not) is added, this forces the [verb] analysis. I think I remember that otherwise 'traditional participle adjectives' are considered indeterminate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hm, so maybe there's a difference between the second ("He felt cheated") and the others which include "... *by* ___"? That seems like an answer...

Comment: @Andy Bonner I'm dredging up what I read in a previous answer to a near-identical question. Duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Devastated - verb or adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338994/devastated-verb-or-adjective)